# Search photos in Instagram where I'm on a photo

Tags: instagram

I want to get photos (where I'm marked) using Instagram API. Is this possible?
I am looking for a way to get it without listing all photos from my followers(Retrieve all photos where I have been tagged).

Comment: Are you talking about pulling photos where you have been tagged in them by yourself or other users? Using Instagrams new functionality for tagging a user in a picture? Or do you just want to retrieve all of the photos from your account?

Comment: Retrieve all photos where I have been tagged

Answer (score 0):

```
//Try This Instagram API ,,,,,,,,,,,,
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=%@
```

Answer (score 0):

The existing Instagram API endpoints don't support finding media tagged by user. I thought that the existing endpoint for finding recent media by tag might work:

```
GET/tags/tag-name/media/recent
```

but it only returned media with matching hashtags. It doesn't search for usernames.

Comment: Hello. I need the same thing as the OP. I know the thread is old, but have you found any solution?